# String search & replace in C

Tags: c, strings, search

I created a function to do that, and I want to know if there is a problem I'm overlooking about it ..

```
void replaceStr(buffer, haystack, needle, rep)
    char *buffer, *needle, *rep;
    const char *haystack;
{
    if (!buffer || !haystack || !needle || !rep)
        return;

    size_t rep_length = strlen(rep);
    long long diff = strlen(needle) - rep_length;
    memcpy(buffer, haystack, strlen(haystack) + 1);

    while ((buffer = strstr(buffer, needle))) {
        memcpy(buffer, rep, rep_length + 1); /* +1 for the null byte */
        if (diff > 0) {
            long long i;
            for (i = diff; i <= diff; ++i)
                buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
            buffer[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is about strings, I would rather use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead of [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). This has the benefit, that it saves the unnecessary `strlen`

```
strcpy(buffer, haystack);
```

You can declare the other parameters `const` too, e.g.

```
char *buffer;
const char *needle, *rep;
```

The `for` loop is a bit confusing, because it copies just one character at offset `diff`, no matter how large `diff` is. If you want to close a potential gap, you could again use `strcpy`

```
size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
...
strcpy(buffer + rep_length, buffer + needle_length);
```

The other way round - if `rep` is larger than `needle`, you need to make space for the larger replacement string. Otherwise, you overwrite parts of `haystack`! (Unless this is what you intended, of course.)

---

You can avoid this, when you copy from `haystack` to `buffer` as you go, something like

```
size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
char *found;
while ((found = strstr(haystack, needle))) {
    /* copy haystack part until needle */
    size_t n = found - haystack;
    strncpy(buffer, haystack, n);
    /* copy replacement string */
    strcpy(buffer + n, rep);
    /* adjust pointers */
    buffer += n + rep_length;
    haystack = found + needle_length;
}

/* copy remaining haystack */
strcpy(buffer, haystack);
```

Comment: Your solution actually raises a SegFault

Comment: Then it needs a review too :-) I only tested it with a simple call like `replaceStr(buffer, "Hello, world!", "world", "Olaf");` and this works properly. How did you test it?

Comment: Oh, yes you're is fine. It seems I just forgot to remove `strcpy(buffer, haystack)` from above :)

Comment: Great! I am glad, it works finally.